# What does 'orbital' mean when speaking wheels?

Tags: wheels, tricks, jumping

I want to build my own dirt jumper, mostly using Octane One parts.

At [this site](http://shop.octane-one.com/cat/wheels/prod/o-o-solar-front-wheel), there's two versions of the wheel. An 15mm orbital and an 20mm orbital. What is the difference, and which is the most common?

Comment: If you want to do some different tricks, it used to be (50 years ago) that people would put, say, 24-inch rims on a 26-inch wheel, using spokes of varying length to produce a wheel that was off-center.  I don't know that you could jump the thing very well, but you could, eg, get the bike to move by rocking back and forth.  (You could probably also get sea-sick.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orbital is the brand name of the hub. 15mm and 20mm are different axle diameters, get the one that matches your fork.

Edit: Most dirt jumping, DH and freeride forks use 20mm, 15mm is a newer standard used mostly for cross country.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized some mtbs doesn't use the 'normal' quick release axel.